# Helium 3 first ionisation energy?

Tags: ionization-energy

Does the Helium 3 isotope have different first ionisation energy than "normal" helium or is it the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved surprisingly difficult to Google, but I found this paper:

[Energy levels for the stable isotopes of atomic helium (4He I and 3He I), Donald C Morton, Qixue Wu, G WF Drake, Canadian Journal of Physics, 2006, 84(2): 83-105](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/p06-009?journalCode=cjp)

that calculates the ionisation energies for ${}^3$He and ${}^4$He.

You would expect the binding energy of the electron to decrease with reduced mass, and that is what the paper reports. The ionisation energy of ${}^3$He is about 0.2% smaller than the ionisation energy of ${}^4$He.

Comment: thank you very much! I would upvote you but I cant becose I dont have enough points

Comment: Converting those values from MHz gives He-4: 24.5873893 eV and He-3: 24.5860927 eV, with uncertainty ~1 in the last digit.